# Can I purchase a CD or DVD with Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Can I purchase a Ubuntu system on a CD or DVD and install it myself? Or can I ship my brand new PC to you for you to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps to create your installation media :
1.Download the .iso file from Ubuntu website.
2.Download a software named Universal USB installer.
3.Run it to create a bootable USB drive.
4.Use the bootable USB drive to test drive Ubuntu or install it.
If you want suggestion on how to install Ubuntu alongside Windows , please feel free to ask.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can either download it from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) or buy CD/DVD from [here](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17).